# No puedo limpiar el buffer del teclado en C

Tags: c, fgets, stdin

En mi código, solicito una serie de datos al usuario mediante la función `gets()` el problema es que en cierto punto del programa al solicitar un dato con `gets()` simplemente se salta a la siguiente solicitud y deja la variable en blanco, he intentado limpiar el buffer de la siguiente manera y no funciona:

```
fflush(stdin);
```

Este es el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct alumnos{
    char nombre[10];
    char dni[20];
    int edad;
};

int main(){
    struct alumnos myalumno[3];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++){
        printf("Ingrese el nombre del alumno %i: ",i+1);
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(myalumno[i].nombre);
        printf("Ingrese el DNI del alumno %i: ",i+1);
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(myalumno[i].dni);
        printf("Ingrese la edad del alumno %i: ",i+1);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%i",&myalumno[i].edad);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomado de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2187514/5622844) que `fflush` solo se utiliza en buffers de salida.

Intenta usar `fpurge`:

```
int main() {
    struct alumnos myalumno[3];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        printf("Ingrese el nombre del alumno %i: ",i+1);
        fpurge(stdin);
        gets(myalumno[i].nombre);
        printf("Ingrese el DNI del alumno %i: ",i+1);
        fpurge(stdin);
        gets(myalumno[i].dni);
        printf("Ingrese la edad del alumno %i: ",i+1);
        fpurge(stdin);
        scanf("%i",&myalumno[i].edad);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Donde...

Si a `fflush` se le da `NULL` por parámetro, este limpiará todos los buffers de salida que estén activos, pero `fpurge` solo toma el buffer de entrada y lo limpia.

Debes tener cuidado con el uso de `fpurge`, no es una solución "portable" a otras plataformas, por lo que deberías tener cuidado al usarlo.

Referencia: [fpurge (En ingles)](http://www.codecogs.com/library/computing/c/stdio.h/fflush.php?alias=fpurge)

Con eso debería funcionar.

Answer (score 3):

Ya que el comportamiento de `fflush` no está definido por el estándar para los flujos de entrada, sólo es seguro que funcione para los flujos de salida (enviando el contenido restante del búfer a la salida). Por lo tanto `fflush` no debes usarlo.

Tampoco es recomendable usar `fpurge` ya que no está definido en C estándar y tampoco es portable a todas las plataformas (como han explicado en otros comentarios). De hecho, en linux no está disponible, aunque sí existe la función `void  __fpurge(FILE *stream)` que hace lo mismo y está dentro de la librería estándar de GNU (glibc).

La posible solución es que manualmente escribas el código que limpie el búfer de entrada hasta que encuentre un salto de línea. Las dos opciones que tienes son:

```
char c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

y la que a mí me parece mejor:

```
scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");
```

En la última opción, se le dice a `scanf` primero que ignore (uso de *) cualquier número de no caracteres en blanco (distinto a tabulador `'\t'`, espacio `' '` o salto de línea `'\n'`) con el especificador `%*[^\n]` hasta que encuentre un carácter en blanco (el salto de línea), en cuyo caso lo ignora con el `%*c`.

El `%*c` no se puede sustituir por `\n` porque en tal caso estarías ordenando en ese punto que ignore cualquier número de caracteres en blanco hasta que encuentre uno que no lo es, haciendo que la función scanf se quede pendiente esperando que introduzcas cualquier no carácter en blanco, el cual no será leído y quedará pendiente en el búfer de entrada para la siguiente llamada a `scanf`.

Hay que tener en cuenta que estas soluciones son válidas en el caso de que el búfer tenga contenido distinto a caracteres en blanco (`' ', '\t' o '\n'`). Si el búfer está vacío quedará esperando a que se introduzcan datos por teclado distintos a caracteres en blanco (datos que ignorará).