# Problema con buffer de entrada -

Tags: c

Tengo un problema con un programa en C. Quiero crear un arreglo de datos de tipo unc, creado previamente con struct. El programa pide ingresar datos tipo string y tipo  int. El programa puede ser compilado pero cuando quiero usar el programa pasa lo siguiente:

- Puedo ingresar lo que se guarda en n a y e de la primera posicion (`l[0]`)
- Despues de escribir una edad para guardar en e de la primera posicion, al apretar enter, no puedo ingresar nada para n de la segunda posicion, como si ya tomara algo del buffer.

Algo como esto:

```
Ingresar n (1):
aca_puedo_escribir
Ingresar a (1):
aca_puedo_escribir
Ingresar e (1):
10
Ingresar n (2): // ACA NO PUEDO INGRESAR NADA
Ingresar a (2):
aca_puedo
Ingresar e (2):
20
```

Es decir, n se "llena solo", como si ya hubiera algo en el  buffer, acá va el código:

```
struct unc{
    char n[30];
    char a[30];
    int e;
    };

int main(){
    struct unc l[5];
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("Ingresar n (%d):\n",i+1);
        gets(l[i].n);
        printf("Ingresar a (%d):\n",i+1);
        gets(l[i].a);
        printf("Ingresar e (%d):\n",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&l[i].e);
        }
```

Comment: No uses `gets( )`, está **eliminada** de los nuevos estandares por lo peligrosa que es; acostumbrate a usar `fgets( )`.

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema es que `scanf()` **no lee el ENTER** que tu pulsas al introducir el entero. Eso es así, y así debe ser.

Puedes intentar varias cosas (la solución depende de cada implementación de esas funciones en particular):

1. `scanf("%d\n",&l[i].e);` ( añade un '\n' ).
2. `scanf("%d",&l[i].e); getc( stdin );` ( recogemos a mano ese ENTER ).

Comment: Lo segundo me sirvio, muchas gracias!

Comment: @Trauma Los usuarios pueden votar [a partir de 15 de reputación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). Hasta entonces, sólo proveen un feedback de votos, que queda registrado en el sistema pero no te otorga puntuación ni un +1. Es importante tener esto en cuenta para no confundir a usuarios nuevos. Y sé que lo estás diciendo en tono de chiste, pero alguien que no lo entiende, puede malinterpretar tu comentario.

Comment: @ssrlee si esta respuesta ayudó a solucionar el problema de tu pregunta, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) haciendo click en el **✔️**, que está bajo las flechas de votación, a la izquierda de la misma (no se te descuenta nada por eso -todo lo contrario, ambos se benefician).

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes problemas para leer, justamente después del scanf vacía el buffer de entrada. Esto lo puedes hacer incluyendo la línea siguiente: `fflush(stdin)`, ya que stdin es el buffer de entrada estandar.

Comment: Probé también poniendo fflush(stdin) antes y despues de cada gets y scanf pero sigue haciendo lo mismo!

Comment: @ssrlee: Arreglada la respuesta. Pruébalo ahora.

Comment: La función `fflush` para el búfer de entrada `stdin` no está definido su comportamiento en el estándar de C. Sólo está definido para los búferes de salida (o de entrada/salida con condiciones). Por lo tanto, lo más probable es que `fflush` no te funcione para `stdin`. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16685/no-puedo-limpiar-el-buffer-del-teclado-en-c/81435#81435