# Para no mostrar letras repetidas

Tags: c, string

Quiero recorrer la palabra e iterar sobre cada una de sus letras. Si detecta que ya se ha impreso, ya no mostrar la letra (con ayuda de un arreglo auxiliar), mi problema es que no se como llevarlo a cabo. –

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

  int conta, conta_car, conta_max, max;
  char car, cadena[1025];

  printf("\n\nIntroduce la cadena que quieres analizar (1024 caracteres max): ");

  fgets(cadena, 1024, stdin);

  cadena[strlen(cadena)-1]=0;

  printf("\n\nIntroduce el caracter que quieres buscar: ");

  scanf("%c", &car);

  conta=0;
  max=0;

  while(cadena[conta]!=0)
  {

    while(cadena[conta]!=0 && cadena[conta]!=car)
      conta++;

    conta_car=0;

    while(cadena[conta]!=0 && cadena[conta]==car)
    {
      conta_car++;

      if(conta_car>max)
      {
        max=conta_car;
        conta_max=1;
      }
      else if(conta_car==max)
        conta_max++;

      conta++;                             
    }
  }

  if(max>0)
    printf("\n\nSe han encontrado %d '%c' consecutivos %d veces.\n\n", max, car, conta_max);
  else
    printf("\n\nNO se ha encontrado el caracter '%c' en la cadena.\n\n", car);

  system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo quieres hacerlo? ¿Con que problemas te encuentras al implementar lo que quieres? ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Quiero recorrer la palabra e iterar sobre cada una de sus letras. Si detecta que ya se ha impreso, ya no mostrar la letra (con ayuda de un arreglo auxiliar), mi problema es que no se como llevarlo a cabo.

Comment: Debes [edit] la pregunta para añadir esa información. Además añade una descripción de lo que hace el programa, detalla mejor qué es lo que quieres conseguir, y pon un título descriptivo. Te recomiendo que [leas este artículo del centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Según lo que he entendido del título, quieres hacer un programa que según "las letras" que se introduzcan, 
es decir, la frace introducida, contar las letras que se repiten a lo largo de toda la frase.

Yo me iria con una alternativa segura, algo como lo siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Usaremos como longitud maxima 1024 caracteres. */
#define MAX_LEN (1024)

int main(void) {
    char b_frase[MAX_LEN] = {0};      /* buffer de entrada */
    int  b_letras[30] = {0};          /* Buffer para las letras. */
    int c = 0, ind = 0, i;            /* Otras variables. */

    /* Pedimos una frase :) */
    printf("Introduzca una frase (Enter para finalizar lectura): ");
    while ((ind < MAX_LEN) && ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n')) { 
        b_frase[ind++] = c; /* Asignamos el elemento a la frase. */
        /* Nos encargamos de ver si es una letra... */
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            ++b_letras[c - 'a'];
        else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            ++b_letras[c - 'A'];
        /* No hacemos nada de lo contrario. */
    }
    b_frase[ind] = 0; /* Agrega el caracter nulo. */

    /* Imprimimos todo :) */
    printf("En la frase:\n%s\n\nLas Siguientes letras se repiten:\n\n", 
           b_frase);

    i = 'a';
    while (i <= 'z') {
        if (!b_letras[i - 'a']) { 
            ++i; continue; 
        }
        printf("%c se repite '%d' veces.\n", i, b_letras[i - 'a']), ++i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Utilizando el siguiente programa, he probado a correrlo con lo siguiente por entrada:

```
hola munda
```

Obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
En la frase:
hola munda

Las Siguientes letras se repiten:
a se repite '2' veces.
d se repite '1' veces.
h se repite '1' veces.
l se repite '1' veces.
m se repite '1' veces.
n se repite '1' veces.
o se repite '1' veces.
u se repite '1' veces.
```

Cabe mencionar que esta implementación ignora cualquier caracter diferente de una letra mayúscula o minuscula y toma todas las letras por igual, probado con la siguiente entrada:

```
AaAbCoOopP
```

Obtengo por salida:

```
En la frase:
AaAbCoOopP

Las Siguientes letras se repiten:

a se repite '3' veces.
b se repite '1' veces.
c se repite '1' veces.
o se repite '3' veces.
p se repite '2' veces.
```

Saludos :)

Answer (score 1):

Mirando tu código para entender el objetivo que quieres alcanzar, aquí te paso una solución que creo se corresponde con tu descripción. Ten presente que uso la función `__purge()` de la librería estándar de GNU para limpiar el búfer de entrada `stdin`, de modo que si te da problemas en otro sistema operativo, simplemente elimina la llamada a esta función.

Cualquier otra duda que tengas respecto al código no dudes en comentarla.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio_ext.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TAM_TEXT_MAX  1024

typedef unsigned short Ushort;
typedef enum {no_encontrada = 0, primera_vez = 1, mas_veces = 2} Aparicion;

int main(void)
{
  char texto[TAM_TEXT_MAX], letra;
  Ushort  longitudTexto, 
          repeticiones = 0,  
          consecutivas = 0,
          totalConsecutivas = 0,
          maxConsecutivas = 0,
          gruposConsecutivas = 0,
          gruposMaxConsecutivas = 0;
  Aparicion aparicion = no_encontrada;

  printf("Introduce el texto: ");
  __fpurge(stdin);
  fgets(texto, TAM_TEXT_MAX, stdin);
  longitudTexto = strlen(texto);

  printf("Introduce la letra: ");
  __fpurge(stdin);
  scanf(" %c", &letra);   // Hay un espacio en formato para ignorar caracteres en blanco.

  for (Ushort i = 0; i <= longitudTexto; ++i)
  {
    if (i < longitudTexto && texto[i] == letra)
    {
      ++repeticiones;
      switch (aparicion)
      {
        case no_encontrada:
          aparicion = primera_vez;
          break;
        case primera_vez:
          consecutivas += 2;
          aparicion = mas_veces;
          break;
        case mas_veces:
          ++consecutivas;
          break;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      switch (aparicion)
      {
        case mas_veces:
          if (consecutivas == maxConsecutivas)
            ++gruposMaxConsecutivas;
          else if (consecutivas > maxConsecutivas)
          {
            maxConsecutivas = consecutivas;
            gruposMaxConsecutivas = 1;
          }
          ++gruposConsecutivas;
          totalConsecutivas += consecutivas;
          consecutivas = 0;

        case primera_vez:
          aparicion = no_encontrada;

        case no_encontrada:
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("Los datos de la letra «%c» en el texto son:\n"
         "%-40s %05hu\n"
         "%-40s %05hu\n"
         "%-42s %05hu\n"
         "%-42s %05hu\n"
         "%-40s %05hu\n", letra,
         "Apariciones totales:", repeticiones,
         "Consecutivas en total:", totalConsecutivas,
         "Máximo nº de consecutivas:", maxConsecutivas,
         "Grupos de máximo nº de consecutivas:", gruposMaxConsecutivas,
         "Grupos totales de consecutivas:", gruposConsecutivas);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo implementaria de otra forma. En lugar de utilizar `fgets()` para pedir la cadena utilizaria `gets()` que es mas facil. Una vez tengas la cadena y la letra a buscar lo suyo seria recorrerla con un bulce `for` y leerlo desde la posicion inicial (i = 0) hasta otra variable que te declares utilizando el `strlen()` que directamente te da la longitud de la cadena asi sabes perfectamente entre que valores de tu cadena te estas moviendo. Una vez hecho eso simplemente es comprobar poscion por posicion a ver si las letras son iguales y en caso de que lo sean comprobar la siguiente posicion para ver si son consecutivas o no. Esto implementado en codigo seria algo asi:

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <stdlib.h>
> #include <string.h>
> #define N 1024
>
>
> int main() {
> char cadena[N]; //Creamos el array que tendra un maximo de N elementos donde N = 1024
> char letra;
> int i, repeticiones = 0, consecutivas = 0, longitud;
>
> printf("\nIntroduce la cadena a analizar: ");
> fflush(stdin);
> gets(cadena);
>
> longitud = strlen(cadena); //Determinamos cuantas de esas 1024 posiciones se han rellenado
>
> printf("\nIntroduce la letra a buscar: ");
> fflush(stdin);
> scanf("%c",&letra);
>
> for(i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
> {
>
>     if(cadena[i] == letra) //Comprobamos si la posicion es igual a la letra y aumentamos el contador en caso de que lo sea
>     {
>         repeticiones = repeticiones + 1;
>
>         if (cadena[i + 1] == letra) //Si la posicion es igual a la letra comprobamos si la siguiente letra es igual
>         {
>             consecutivas = consecutivas + 1;
>         }
>     }
>
> }
>
> printf("\nEl numero de repeticiones de la letra %c es: %i de las cuales son consecutivas %i\n\n\n",letra,repeticiones,consecutivas);
>
> return 0; 
> }
> ```

Tambien puedes hacerlo de otra manera pero es la forma mas rapida que se me ha ocurrido. Espero que te sirva

Comment: [Utilizar `gets()` es considerado mala practica](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22419911/5622844) :)

Comment: El comentario de @NaCl es completamente cierto. Usa mejor fgets ya que te permite limitar la longitud máxima de caracteres de la entrada, algo bastante útil ya que los arrays son de longitud fija.

Comment: Además, fflush(stdin) no está definido su comportamiento en el estándar para flujos de entrada (sólo está definido para flujos de salida), por lo tanto, es bastante posible que no limpie el búfer de entrada. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16685/no-puedo-limpiar-el-buffer-del-teclado-en-c/81435#81435

Comment: Y otro posible fallo en tu código es que, en el caso de recibir una cadena de longitud N-1 (la máxima longitud de cadena que puede guardar tu array es N-1 ya que la última posición con índice N-1 guardaría fin de cadena '\0'), en la última iteración N-1 del bucle, en el caso de cumplir la primera condición (comparar letra con caracter de índice N-2) pasaría a realizar la segunda condición donde compararía la letra con el carácter de índice N-1, el cual sería el caracter nulo. Es decir, empiezarías a acceder fuera de la cadena.

Comment: Otro posible error es que, desde el segundo carácter de la cadena hasta el último, estaría siendo comparado dos veces, algo que no es eficiente porque no es necesario para resolver el problema. Además, la variable `consecutivas` no guardaría el número de letras que son consecutivas, sino el número de letras que tienen a continuación la misma letra que estamos comparando. No es lo mismo.