# Código para pedir calificaciones y nombres de alumnos en C

Tags: c

estoy empezando en este mundo y tengo que hacer un código que pida 10 nombres de alumnos y sus respectivas calificaciones, sacando promedio, mayor, menor, entre otros. 
Al momento he realizado esto pero al pedir notas y que sean entre 1.0 a 7.0, entra a if imprimiendo  siempre el error y no he podido averiguar el por qué:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
```

/*Se pide realizar un programa que gestiona las notas de una clase de 10 alumnos. El programa debe permitir solicitar el nombre del alumno 
(debe aceptar espacios) y la nota promedio (la nota debe ser de 1 a 7). 
Con la información recolectada el programa debe entregar la siguiente información:

El promedio de todas las notas.
El promedio de las notas menores de 5.
Mostrar el alumno que tiene la mejor nota.
Mostrar el alumno que tiene la peor nota.

Consideraciones

Se evaluará el uso de vectores de cadenas
Se evaluará el uso de vectores
Se evaluará el uso de estructuras de control
Validación de ingreso de notas
Uso correcto de definición de tipo de datos
*/

```
int main()
{

    int x;
    float nota [10], promedio = 0; 
    char nom [10][50];
    float mayor , menor, total;
    mayor= nota[0];
    menor= nota[0];


    for(x=0;x<10;x++){
    printf("Ingrese nombre de alumno n° %i: " , x+1);
    gets( nom[x]);
    fflush (stdin);      
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(x=0;x<10;x++){
    do{
    printf("Ingrese nota de %s: ",  nom[x]);
    scanf("&f" , &nota[x]);
    fflush (stdin);
        if (nota[x] <=0 || nota[x] >= 70)    
        printf("Nota mal ingresada, vuelva a introducir\n");
    }while  (nota[x] < 0 || nota[x] > 70);  


    }


    mayor= nota[0]; 
    for (x=0; x<10; x++){
        if (nota[x]> mayor){
            mayor=nota[x];
        }

        if (nota[x]< menor){
            menor=nota[x];
        }

         for (x=0; x<10; x++){
            promedio+=nota[x];
    }
    printf("\nEl mayor es %f\n\n", mayor);
    printf("El menor es %f\n\n", menor);

    promedio = promedio/10.0;
    printf("El Promedio es: %.2f\n\n", promedio);
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 1;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios errores en tu codigo, los iremos analizando paso a paso:

1. No utilices gets: El uso de gets esta descontinuado en C, se recomienda utilizar mejor `printf-scanf` para impresion y captura de datos.
2. El problema tuyo: `fflush` sirve para borrar el flujo saliente, pero el entrante no, segun lo que encontre [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16685/no-puedo-limpiar-el-buffer-del-teclado-en-c). Como reemplazo, se puede utilizar `while(getchar()!='\n');` para borrar el flujo, se utiliza despues del `scanf` para eliminar el flujo de datos de entrada.
3. Falla en tu logica: En el codigo que tienes tiene cosas incoherentes. Vamos por partes. La primera es la condicion `nota[x] <=0 || nota[x] >= 70`. Si bien esta bien, lo mejor es invertir las condiciones, de tal manera que cuando la note este en el rango encontrado ingrese la nota en la lista, de lo contrario tendria que repetir el bloque de codigo pidiendo de nuevo la nota. Si la nota esta bien el segundo ciclo se rompe pudiendo ingresar la nota al siguiente estudiante. El codigo quedaria de la siguiente manera:

   ```
   for(x=0;x<10;x++){
       do{
           printf("Ingrese nota de %s: ",  nom[x]);
           float nota_temp = 0;
           scanf("%f" , &nota_temp);
           //while(getchar()!='\n');
           if (nota[x] >= 0 || nota[x] <= 70){
               nota[x] = nota_temp;
               break;
           } else{
               printf("Nota mal ingresada, vuelva a introducir\n");
           }
       }while(true);
   }
   ```

   Para que funcione corerctamente debes de agregar en la cabecera de tu proyecto las siguientes macros:

```
#define false 0
#define true 1
```

4. La logica de encontrar el menor esta mal: Estas metiendo en la misma logica el codigo de encontrar el menor y el mayor, cosa que no es correcta dentro de la logica. Para encontrar el mayor necesitabamos un numero lo menor posible. Como tienes un rango de notas entre 0 a 70, lo recomendable es iniciar `mayor` con el valor `-1`. Para el menor es al contrario, toca iniciarlo con el numero mayor posible. Como encontramos anteriormente el mayor, podemos hacer `menor = mayor`.

```
int x;
float nota [10], promedio = 0; 
char nom [10][50];
float mayor = -1 , menor = -1, total;
mayor= nota[0];
mayor= nota[0]; 
for (x=0; x<10; x++){
    if (nota[x]> mayor){
        mayor=nota[x];
    }
}
menor = mayor;
for (x=0; x<10; x++){
     promedio+=nota[x];
}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    if (nota[i] < menor){
        menor = nota[i];
    }
}
```

En conclusion, el error principal, que responde a la pregunta es: Te saltaba el error debido a que fflush no borra el flujo de entrada que queda, haciendo que se salte todas las instrucciones debido a los caracteres basura que quedan.

El codigo, en su totalidad queda de la siguiente manera:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define false 0
#define true 1 // Option 1

int main()
{

    int x;
    float nota [10], promedio = 0; 
    char nom [10][50];
    float mayor = -1 , menor = -1, total;
    mayor= nota[0];


    for(x=0;x<10;x++){
        printf("Ingrese nombre de alumno n° %i: " , x+1);
        scanf("%s", &nom[x]);
        while(getchar()!='\n');
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(x=0;x<10;x++){
        do{
            printf("Ingrese nota de %s: ",  nom[x]);
            float nota_temp = 0;
            scanf("%f" , &nota_temp);
            while(getchar()!='\n');
            if (nota[x] >= 0 || nota[x] <= 70){
                nota[x] = nota_temp;
                break;
            } else{
                printf("Nota mal ingresada, vuelva a introducir\n");
            }
        }while(true);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("%f \n", nota[i]);
    }

    mayor= nota[0]; 
    for (x=0; x<10; x++){
        if (nota[x]> mayor){
            mayor=nota[x];
        }
    }
    menor = mayor;
    for (x=0; x<10; x++){
            promedio+=nota[x];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if (nota[i] < menor){
            menor = nota[i];
        }
    }
    printf("\nEl mayor es %f\n\n", mayor);
    printf("El menor es %f\n\n", menor);

    promedio = promedio/10.0;
    printf("El Promedio es: %.2f\n\n", promedio);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 1;

}
```

**ACTUALIZACION:** He actualizado el codigo para que pueda aceptar cadenas de string con especios en la entrada de flujo de la consola, esto li hice utilizando la funcion `fgets`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define false 0
#define true 1 // Option 1

int main()
{

    int x;
    float nota [10], promedio = 0; 
    char nom [10][50];
    float mayor = -1 , menor = -1, total;
    mayor= nota[0];


    for(x=0;x<10;x++){
        printf("Ingrese nombre de alumno n° %i: " , x+1);
        fgets(nom[x], 100, stdin);
        while(getchar()!='\n');
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(x=0;x<10;x++){
        do{
            printf("Ingrese nota de %s: ",  nom[x]);
            float nota_temp = 0;
            scanf("%f" , &nota_temp);
            while(getchar()!='\n');
            if (nota[x] >= 0 || nota[x] <= 70){
                nota[x] = nota_temp;
                break;
            } else{
                printf("Nota mal ingresada, vuelva a introducir\n");
            }
        }while(true);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("%f \n", nota[i]);
    }

    mayor= nota[0]; 
    for (x=0; x<10; x++){
        if (nota[x]> mayor){
            mayor=nota[x];
        }
    }
    menor = mayor;
    for (x=0; x<10; x++){
            promedio+=nota[x];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if (nota[i] < menor){
            menor = nota[i];
        }
    }
    printf("\nEl mayor es %f\n\n", mayor);
    printf("El menor es %f\n\n", menor);

    promedio = promedio/10.0;
    printf("El Promedio es: %.2f\n\n", promedio);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 1;

}
```

Adicional a esto, agrego un compilador y editor de codigo de C, el enlace lo puedes encontrar [aqui](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler)

Comment: *se recomienda utilizar mejor printf-scanf para impresion y captura de datos..* Con la función *scanf* también puede ocurrir buffer overflow si no se especifica el tamaño del buffer en el especificador de formato, sin embargo, lo ideal seria usar la función `fgets` para admitir espacios cuando se vaya leer una cadena. Además, permite especificar el tamaño del buffer.

Comment: Hola @Carlos, muchas gracias por el tiempo! he entendido los puntos comentados pero el Fgets lo necesito para poder guardar nombres con espacios, lo del [fflush] no me ha quedado tan claro pero le daré una vuelta más, lo otro es que en el código que me mandas, al ingresar las notas solo entra al else e imprime el mensaje y no me deja seguir ingresando las demás notas, a ti te pasa lo mismo?

Comment: @Sebastiil El codigo esta funcionan perfectamente. Lo pruebes probar en la web que voy a dejar arriba en la publicacion. Posiblemente estes ingresando nombres con espacio y eso este provocando problemas. Ya voy acorregir el codigo.

Comment: @Sebastiil Mira el codigo y trata de correrlo en el compilador online que es ahi donde lo probe.

Comment: Muchas gracias! el problema es con el compilador que estoy ocupando ya que en el web que me indicas funciona perfecto, veré si cambia algo al pasarlo a mi compilador, muchas gracias! Lo último en lo que te molesto, Carlos, hay alguna manera de no tener que darle dos veces Enter para que me pida el nombre siguiente?

Comment: @Sebastiil De nada estimado. Con respecto a lo del doble enter si, debajo del fgets esta el while,solo documentalo, en el codigo que agregue arriba ya aparece documentado.