# como evitar que se rompa el siguiente programa al ingresar muchos 0 por teclado

Tags: c, windows, dev-c++, begin-cbegin

estoy haciendo un programa que calcule el promedio de un array pero a la hora de hacer que el programa verifique los datos ingresado por el teclado me di cuenta que tengo un error, que cuando marco 0 durante un rato y doy enter el programa directamente termina en vez de regresarme la verificación que el numero supero el limite, me pueden ayudar con este problema, aquí a continuación les dejo el código ( disculpen si es algo confuso estoy aprendiendo todavía )

creo entender que es que supero el limite del buffer y por eso el programa termina abruptamente, pero no se como hacer para limitar dicho ingreso al usuario.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include <math.h>


int verificarnum (char*);


int main (){
    
int numero,i,matriz[10],suma=0,verificado;  
char verificar[40]; 
float promedio; 

for (i=0;i<10;i++){

    do{
        printf ("numero %d que sacar el promedio : ", i+1);
        scanf("%s",verificar);
        fflush (stdin);
        verificado=verificarnum(verificar);
    }   while (verificado == 0);
            
matriz[i]= atoi(verificar); 
system ("cls");     
            
}
printf ("los numeros que ingreso son los siguientes: \n");
for (i=0;i<10;i++){
    
    printf ("%5d",matriz[i]);
 
    
}
    
    printf ("\n");
    system("pause");

for (i=0;i<10;i++){
    
    suma= suma+matriz[i];
    
    
}   

promedio = (float)suma/10;

printf ("\nel promedio es: %.2f ", promedio);
    
    
}


int verificarnum(char numero[])
{
    int i,longitud;


    longitud= strlen(numero);

    for (i=0;i<longitud;++i)
    {
        if  (!(isdigit(numero[i]))) 
        {
            
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\ningresar solo numeros. \n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    
        if (longitud>5) 
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nexcedio el limite de datos por teclado.  \n");
        getch();
        return 0;
    }
 
    return 1;   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De todas formas aquí va la versión corregida código del anterior:

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++){

    do{
        printf ("numero %d que sacar el promedio : ", i+1);
        scanf("%40s",verificar);//se cambió %40c por %40s
        char c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
        fflush (stdin);
    
        verificado=verificarnum(verificar);
    }   while (verificado == 0);
        
matriz[i]= atoi(verificar); 
system ("cls");     
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Estimado:

Revisando su código y ejecutándolo en un compilador en c, tal y como usted señala cuando se ingresa un numero muy largo (puede ser cualquiera) se cierra el programa. Por lo que pude averiguar, efectivamente se produce un problema de memoria en el buffer de entrada por el ingreso de este dato muy largo.

Para una posible solución recurrí al siguiente tema:
[No puedo limpiar el buffer del teclado en C](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16685/no-puedo-limpiar-el-buffer-del-teclado-en-c)

Allí mencionaban como limpiar el buffer de memoria. En el código que se muestra a continuación esta la versión modificada, solo se muestra el ciclo for en el main() ya que solo en esta parte se realizaron modificaciones dentro de su código:

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++){

    do{
        printf ("numero %d que sacar el promedio : ", i+1);
        scanf("%40c",verificar);
        char c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
        fflush (stdin);
    
        verificado=verificarnum(verificar);
    }   while (verificado == 0);
        
matriz[i]= atoi(verificar); 
system ("cls");     
        
}
```

Adicionalmente hubo que limitar la cantidad de caracteres que se iban a utilizar dentro del scanf (a 40).

Comment: me funciono pero usando el %40s en vez de %40c

Comment: Si, fue error mío, debe ser una 's' y no una 'c'.

Comment: gracias de todas maneras, ya con eso pude resolver. que tengas un muy buen dia.